# How to set an active page at the first execution of a view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a function inside my plugin project (a plugin which contains a view), that creates selection listeners for an active page (for example: package explorer, resource navigator).

At the first execution of an Eclipse instance sometimes I don't have an active page and the following is null:

```
ISelectionService selectionService=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

So that a selection listener cannot be setted for another view:

```
selectionService.addSelectionListener(partID,listener);
```

My problem is actually that the function doesn't executes the above line since the selectionService is null.

What should I do in order to avoid this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a `IWindowListener` to the `IWorkbench` and then add the selection listener in the `windowOpened` event:

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench(); 

workbench.addWindowListener(window listener);

...

@Override
public void windowOpened(IWorkbenchWindow window)
{
  window.getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(selection listener);
}
```

Comment: I get an exception Widget is disposed....how to remove all the listeners when I close the view ? (without removing them by id)

Comment: You can use `IPartService.addPartListener` from `IWokbenchWindow.getPartService` to listen for parts closing (among other events).

Comment: I close the view and when I reopen it it isn't refreshed because the buttons and tables and other objects on it are disposed....is this a listener problem ?

Comment: This is a new question